# Multiplexer behaviour with no power?

Tags: solar-cell, multiplexer

I am using the ISL84781 8-to-1 Analog Multiplexer. The use case is that the multiplexer is going to go on a cubesat for testing power output from some experimental solar cells. I am not quite sure I can figure out what will happen when the board is not receiving power. Will signals into the channels be blocked or conduct?

[image]

The cells will be connected to the NOx channels and connected to the COM pin is the subcircuit which is doing the measurement. As I have mentioned, due to the PCB going on a cubesat at certain points it will not have power - however the cells may be generating power due to sunlight.

The desired behaviour is that there is high impedance unless we open the channel. This allows us to put a resistive load across the cells when they are not in use meaning the don't degrade as fast.

https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/isl84781-datasheet

Comment: In the datasheet, there are operating range limits listed as numbers, and even a picture of how to safely bypass them, did you see those?

Answer (score 1):

quoting from the [data sheet you linked to](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/isl84781-datasheet) (with my emphasis)

> V+ must be applied before any input signals, **and the input
> signal voltages must remain between V+ and GND**. If these
> conditions cannot be guaranteed, then one of the following
> two protection methods should be employed.
>
> Logic inputs can easily be protected by adding a 1kΩ
> resistor in series with the input (see Figure 7). The resistor
> limits the input current below the threshold that produces
> permanent damage, and the sub-microamp input current
> produces an insignificant voltage drop during normal
> operation.
>
> This method is not applicable for the signal path inputs.
> Adding a series resistor to the switch input defeats the
> purpose of using a low rON switch, so two small signal
> diodes can be added in series with the supply pins to provide
> overvoltage protection for all pins (see Figure 7). These
> additional diodes limit the analog signal from 1V below V+ to
> 1V above GND. The low leakage current performance is
> unaffected by this approach, but the switch signal range is
> reduced and the resistance may increase, especially at low
> supply voltages.

It may be that schottky diodes will allow less than 1 V sacrifice in analogue voltage levels.

The way that these series diodes work is to allow the protection diodes within the chip to power it, without drawing excessive current back-driving the whole power rail on the board.

You may be able to design a cleverer power supply protection using FETs, perhaps simply active rectifying all your solar cells to provide a VCC to this chip whenever any cell is active.

OTOH, it may be better to do a design from a blank sheet of paper using discrete FETs as the switching elements. This will allow you to have complete control over the response to various configrations of power supply prescence